# How to avoid footnote split?

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes

Maybe the second footnote is too long, it splits into two parts at the bottom of the page as following picture shows.

[image]

What should I do to avoid this? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? Please post a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem. People are more likely to give you useful responses if it is easy to help!

Comment: I want the second footnote to show at the same column rather than splitting into two column.

Comment: And the code? Note that TeX is breaking it to avoid other undesirable effects so preventing that may make things worse in other ways. TeX tries to choose the lesser evil. Avoiding that evil means preferring a worse one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `\interfootnotelinepenalty` to 10,000.

Comment: Would be nice to be more verbose, similar to [TeX Frequently Asked Questions -- question label "splitfoot"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=splitfoot). Perhaps you can also point to [How can I let a footnote continue on the next page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37613/how-can-i-let-a-footnote-continue-on-the-next-page), where the opposite was asked.